# Creating a quest, problem with chips for pass weapons from subroom to subroom

Tags: rec-room

We are a bunch of fans of rec room and we want to have our own quest, but... sadly there must be something we are not doing right, because is not working.  What we need is to spawn weapons in one subroom, but we have a big problem.

First in the lobby, I store the ID of the gun in the leaderboard, and that’s fine.  The problem begins when I enter the next subroom and the object respawner doesn’t spawn the gun that I had in the previous room.

It looks like the ID object change and it doesn’t drop the item I want.  I have no idea of what to do to spawn the object I had in the previous room.

In the lobby, I use a trigger zone (for objects) (when entering) goes to a random chip to the 3 channels RGB.  This gives to me the Object ID and goes to the set leaderboard chip (Value) B channel, and goes to the object mapper R channel.  Then this goes to R channel from set leaderboard chip; in the set leaderboard chip the G channel is 1. (this is all ok)

In the next subroom I have a push button R channel goes to Get Leaderboard stat Chip, in this chip the G channel is 1 and from the output the B channel goes to Object Respawner (G channel (ID Object)). This is the wrong part because it doesn’t give me the gun from the previous subroom.

I add some images to let you see it better.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems very long. Can you shorten it?

Comment: You say it's not spawning the item from the previous room.  What is it spawning?  Is it the same item each time, or does it change?  I'm not familiar with Rec Room, but if you are including snippets of code, it might help to [format your post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) so it's easier to distinguish.

Answer (score 1):

### Object IDs

The problem with your system is related to your use of Object IDs. The way object IDs work in Rec Room is that when you save a room, all the objects in it are assigned an Object ID based on some unknown parameters. Every time you save, the object ID changes. As a result, there is no persistent Object ID that's shared across items in different subrooms- instead, the same sword like you have in your example will likely have a different Object ID in every subroom. You should convince yourself of this by looking at the actual object ID of that sword in each subroom- you should see that it's different in all subrooms.

### Solution

To accomplish what you want to do, (i.e. spawn the weapon that a player selects in different subrooms), you'll need to create your own ID system. Assign an ID to each of the weapons and store that number in the leaderboard instead of the Object ID. If you have 4 weapons that players can select, you would store the numbers 1-4 in the leaderboard. Then in the subroom, you would have to decode that ID back to the object you want to select.

One way to do this in this example is to tag each weapon with a unique tag (e.g. `#weapon1`, `#weapon2`, `weapon3`, `weapon4`), then have 4 object spawners that are configured to spawn each of those tags respectively. Then, from the leaderboard chip that is storing the ID of the weapon, pass that through a selector chip that routes the signal to the correct object spawner. i.e. if there's a 1 in the leaderboard stat, then the `#weapon1` object spawner is activated. If it's 3, then the `#weapon3` object spawner is activated.

Comment: Are leaderboards updated quickly enough between subrooms for this to work reliably?

Comment: Yes. I've used a system like this and never ran into problems.